# how to query dataframe in for loop with changing values, ValueError: Lengths must match to compare?

Tags: pandas, select

This works, but I had to type 4 different times for each value in charge_names list

```
charge_names = ['Vehicle Theft','Robbery','Burglary','Receive Stolen Property']

charges[charges['Charge Group Description']== 'Vehicle Theft'].head(2)
```

I tried to run for loop like this:

```
charge_names = ['Vehicle Theft','Robbery','Burglary','Receive Stolen Property']
for name in charge_names:
    charges[charges['Charge Group Description']== name].head(2)
```

but not much success.

this is not working:

```
charges[['Charge Group Description'].isin(['Robbery', 'Burglary'])]
```

How can I query for all 4 values in the charge_names list in one line?

Comment: charges[charges['Charge Group Description'].isin(charge_names)]?

Comment: @perl, thx u yes! i forgot to write charges again inside..

Comment: Yes, exactly! You're most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrame.isin` Whether each element in the DataFrame is contained in values.

`DataFrame.groupby` Group DataFrame based on entries

```py
charge_names = ['Vehicle Theft','Robbery','Burglary','Receive Stolen Property']
charges[charges['Charge Group Description'].isin(charge_names)].groupby('Charge Group Description').head(2)
```